# Spring JPA save entity. MySQLSyntaxErrorException error

Tags: mysql, spring, entity-framework, jpa

I have a accountant entity class. I am saving it and get the error below.Attached my entity class, controller, mysql table creation script. Not sure what the error is.
Thanks so much for  helping!

```
2018-02-09 16:00:02.417 ERROR 11164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_timestamp, email, email_verified, ic_number, name, password, phone_numbe' at line 1
```

The accountant table created in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accountant (
    accountant_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ic_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status int(11) NOT NULL,
    verification_code  VARCHAR(255),
    email_verified varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY (accountant_id) 
);
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTANT ADD COLUMN `current_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

The entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accountant")
public class Accountant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "accountant_id", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "ic_number")
    private String icNumber;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "verification_code")
    private String verificationCode;

    @Column(name = "email_verified")
    private String emailVerified;

    @Column(name = "current_timestamp")
    private Timestamp currentTimeStamp;
}
```

Service class is:

```
@Service("accountantService")
public class AccountantServiceImpl implements AccountantService{

    @Autowired
    private AccountantRepository accountantRepository;

    @Override
    public Accountant saveAccountant(Accountant newAccountant, String role) {
        return accountantRepository.save(newAccountant);
    }
}
```

The AccountantRepository  class is:

```
@Repository("accountantRepository")
@Transactional
public interface AccountantRepository extends JpaRepository<Accountant, Long> {

    Accountant findByEmail(String email);
    Accountant findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: Sadly your chosen JPA provider doesn't auto-quote SQL keywords, so you have to either rename the column, or put quote marks around it yourself in the `@Column`. Or use a JPA provider that does it for you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the column current_timestamp. Because current_timestamp is a MySQL function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html